# Update categories in two Series / Columns for comparison

Tags: pandas, numpy, categorical-data

If I try to compare two Series with different categories I get an error:

```
a = pd.Categorical([1, 2, 3])
b = pd.Categorical([4, 5, 3])
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b], columns=['a', 'b'])

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  3

df.a == df.b

# TypeError: Categoricals can only be compared if 'categories' are the same.
```

What is the best way to update categories in both Series? Thank you!

My solution:

```
df['b'] = df.b.cat.add_categories(df.a.cat.categories.difference(df.b.cat.categories))
df['a'] = df.a.cat.add_categories(df.b.cat.categories.difference(df.a.cat.categories))
df.a == df.b
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: convert one to obj: df.a.astype('object').eq(df.b) ??

Comment: @Nk03 Possible solution. I don't know if it's a good way if you have a big dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea with `union_categoricals`:

```
from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals

union = union_categoricals([df.a, df.b]).categories

df['a'] = df.a.cat.set_categories(union)
df['b'] = df.b.cat.set_categories(union)
print (df.a == df.b)
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```