# Python Pandas how to test equality between pandas columns that are category data types

Tags: python, pandas

I have large datasets that I cross-join with python pandas. Both datasets load in pandas and I convert all 'object' columns to 'category'. The issue is I need to pd.query() against various 'category' dtype columns. When doing so with 'category' columns it returns an error (I expect this because not all columns have the same values (e.g. subsets and supersets that exist in both, one, or none). However, in the pd.query() method I can convert each via df["col1"].astype("object") and test against another object column. When comparing "object" types my datasets grow in memory size to Gigabytes and I run into MemoryError. Is there something I'm unaware of that may allow me to test equality between two or more 'category' dtype columns that have varying range of values? Example code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"c1":["a","b","c","d"],
                   "c2":["d","e","f","d"]})

print(df)
print()

df["c1"] = df["c1"].astype("category")
df["c2"] = df["c2"].astype("category")

### testing equality of category column dtypes
try : df.query("c1 == c2")
except: print("ERROR: we know this returns 'ValueError: unkown type object' bc comparing 'category' column dtypes ")
print()

dfObj = df.query("c1.astype('object') == c2.astype('object')")
print("NO ERROR because during comparions converted 'category' to 'object'!")
print(dfObj)
```

Result:

```
  c1 c2
0  a  d
1  b  e
2  c  f
3  d  d

ERROR: we know this returns 'ValueError: unkown type object' bc comparing 'category' column dtypes 

NO ERROR because during comparions converted 'category' to 'object'!
  c1 c2
3  d  d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union_categoricals` to do what you want.

Then to compare your two columns you code will look like this:

```
from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals

union = union_categoricals([df.c1, df.c2]).categories

df['c1'] = df.c1.cat.set_categories(union)
df['c2'] = df.c2.cat.set_categories(union)

print (df.c1 == df.c2)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
```

Here is the doc if you need more ample details:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.union_categoricals.html

This post is a duplicate of this question:

[Update categories in two Series / Columns for comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67469654/update-categories-in-two-series-columns-for-comparison)

Comment: TSS22 This is correct and does work. Unfortunately, I did not adequately state my problem. I'm working with two dataframes so need to find a way for it work with something like df1['c1'] == df2['c2']. 

I tried unioning them all during initial loading and but once new dataframes are created (including subset of objects as categories, the mapping must be different???).  I did set_categories based on the union variable but still returned an error when comparing categoricals between different dataframes. I had no problem comparing columns in the same dataframe!

Comment: Wouldn't importing the category as simple string works for your setup ?
Because 

import pandas as pd;

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"c1":["a","b","c","d"]});
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c2":["d","e","f","d"]});

print(df1["c1"]==df2["c2"]);

Works just fine

Comment: By the way, union seems to works fine too:
import pandas as pd;
`from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals;
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"c1":["a","b","c","d"]});
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c2":["d","e","f","d"]});
df1["c1"] = df1["c1"].astype("category");
df2["c2"] = df2["c2"].astype("category");
union = union_categoricals([df1.c1, df2.c2]).categories;
df1['c1'] = df1.c1.cat.set_categories(union);
df2['c2'] = df2.c2.cat.set_categories(union);
print(df1["c1"]==df2["c2"]);`

Comment: TSS22 This works on this example. I keep receiving a 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series Objects'. After adapting your working and correct example to my set of two different columns from different dataframes, the error is because the columns are different lengths (e.g. df1.c1 has 4 rows and df2.c2. has 7 rows). I don't know what the .cat.set_categories() does underneath the hood to determine how the category labels are compared.

Comment: `import pandas as pd;
from pandas.api.types import union_categoricals;
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"c1":["a","b","c","d" , "b" , "c" , "x" ]});
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c2":["d","e","f","d" , "y" ]});
df1["c1"] = df1["c1"].astype("category");
df2["c2"] = df2["c2"].astype("category");
union = union_categoricals([df1.c1, df2.c2]).categories;
df1['c1'] = df1.c1.cat.set_categories(union);
df2['c2'] = df2.c2.cat.set_categories(union);
print(df1["c1"]==df2["c2"]);`

Comment: Do you want to compare only the common part ? (for example if you got a columns of 5 and a columns of 7 you only compare on the first five) or do you want to know if the element of df2 appear in df1 (not accounting for any potential redundancy of the values in any of them ?